# Get autocomplete when overriding methods from inherited python class in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

In IntelliJ we have a function which lets us get autcomplete and assistance for adding an inherited function.

Is there any way to recreate this behaviour in VS Code with the build in Python interpreter?

**It lets us override specific functions by using ctrl+O**

[image: It lets us override specific functions by using ctrl+O]

**It lets us see which methods in the current class is overridden.**

[image: It lets us see which methods in the current class is overridden.]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently any equivalent functionality. Please feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python for the idea.