# How to get list of parent methods in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

In PyCharm I can hit Ctrl/Cmd + O and it'll give me a modal with all methods I can override. What's the equivalent in VSCode?

Comment: Here is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60772989/13944524, Brett Cannon in dev team said it's not implemented yet.

Comment: Be epic and write a pull request for PyLance